# Define a geometry region using 'for' loop in MuMax3

Tags: geometry-optimization, algorithms, mumax3

I was trying to define regions using a 'for' loop.

Please find the regions:

```
defregion(0, xrange(-1024e-9, -964e-9))
defregion(1, xrange(-964e-9, -844e-9))
defregion(2, xrange(-844e-9, -784e-9))
defregion(3, xrange(-784e-9, -664e-9))
defregion(4, xrange(-664e-9, -604e-9))
defregion(5, xrange(-604e-9, -484e-9))
...
```

Here, the periodicity is `w1=60e-9`, and `w2=120e-9`.

So I was trying to define the regions using a loop like in the following way:

```
    l=1024e-9
    w1=60e-9
    w2=120e-9

    for i := 0; i <= 5; i+=2 {
        defregion(i, xrange(-l+i*w2, -l+(i+1)*w1));
        for j:=i+1; j<= 5; j+=1{
            defregion(j, xrange(-l+j*w1, -l+(j+1)*w2))
            }
    }
```

In this case, the software forms the geometry only with the `w1` value. The `w2` value is not taken.
However, the required geometry has not been formed.

Could anyone please let me know where I am wrong and how to solve this problem?

I have tried with the following solution (got it from the first answer!)

```
l=1024e-9
w1=60e-9
w2=120e-9

for i := 0; i <= 5; i+=2 {
    defregion(i, xrange(-l+i*w2, -l+(i+1)*w1));
    for j:=i+1; j<= 5; j+=1{
        defregion(j, xrange(-l+j*w1, -l+(j+1)*w2))
        }
}
```

And, the error looks like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 but can you copy and paste that error message into a `code` block rather than uploading an image which won't load in browsers that have on-site images turned off for faster browsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used MuMax3 before, so I may be missing something, but I think you are overcomplicating things by trying to use a nested loop. It looks like you define a region in one loop and then redefine in another iteration, so its tough to reason out what values you will get.

Running the equivalent of your loops in Python, I get

```
0 (-1.024e-06, -9.64e-07)
1 (-9.64e-07, -7.84e-07)
2 (-7.84e-07, -8.440000000000001e-07)
3 (-8.440000000000001e-07, -5.440000000000001e-07)
4 (-5.440000000000001e-07, -7.240000000000001e-07)
5 (-7.240000000000001e-07, -3.040000000000002e-07)
```

I believe you could instead use a single loop to get the result you want.

```
l:=1024e-9
w1:=60e-9
w2:=120e-9

start:=0
stop:=0
swap:=0
for i := 0; i <= 5; i+=1 {
    stop=stop+w1
    defregion(i, xrange(-l+start, -l+stop));
    swap=w1
    w1=w2
    w2=swap
    start=start+w2
}
```

The `start` and `stop` store how much you should add to the initial value to get the next interval. At each iteration, `w1` and `w2` are swapped so that the beginning and end of each region increase by the correct amount, which alternates.

Initially, my answer used `=` everywhere rather than `:=`. It seems, based on the examples I could find on the MuMax3 page, that `=` is used to set options for the program or redefine existing variables while `:=` is used for user created variable assignment.

Comment: @ArindamSamanta Since its getting a little long here, I'm moving this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58799384#58799384)